# how minify css files works in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in mvc4 i read this article to find what is bundle and minify in mvc4

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725

i create an new sample project to test css minifing and add tree css file in my theme folder
and

```
public class BundleConfig
{

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/default/public.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/default/home.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/default/footer.css"));
     }
```

and in my master layout :

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

it works fine but i can not understand minifying because when i look at my net thab on firebug tolls i saw  my page loads that three css files I'm confuse on two things

1-why it load that css file is it normally or browser should load one file with all of my css files contains?

2-i should create minifiyng folder and minify my css an remove comments and.. and use theme
on my project or i use some configs until mvc do it  by itself?

Comment: by default the framework does the minification part only in release mode, while you are working in your development environment locally (in debug mode) the framework will not minify, unless you explicitly tell it to via your web.config file

Answer (score 7):

First change it to release mode, as it only works in this mode, not Debug.

If you haven't already done so, in your BundleConfig, add:

```
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

Run in your application in Release mode:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

and watch what happens.

Comment: yes it is correcct i do this and works fine but i have a div tag with  background image but whe i change it to release mode can not found background picture :background-image: url("images/mainpic.jpg");